# How can i decrease boostrap's form-control width without using the responsivness

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this html

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="form-control-label" for="salary" name="salary">Specify the salary for <span
          class="user-detail">{{user?.first_name}}</span></label>
        <input id="salary" class="form-control form-control-alternative" type="text">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

when I apply `form-control` then the input goes till the end of the parent container.
Here I will need to write numbers on the input so it will be too big.

How can I decrease its size ?

If I try to apply custom style

```
.form-control {
  width:200px !important;
}
```

then it starts to be inline-block instead like block element.

Comment: It is working as expected per bootstrap design since you are inside of col-md-12, using the full 12 columns. Either use less columns or set a max-width in CSS or override the width for your scenario in CSS in all necessary areas including in the media queries for responsive design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Bootstrap's column sizing on form controls. Here I'm using `col-*` for various sizes.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="form-control-label" for="salary" name="salary">Specify the salary for <span
          class="user-detail">{{user?.first_name}}</span></label>
        <input id="salary" class="form-control form-control-alternative col-4" type="text">
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="form-control-label" for="salary" name="salary">Specify the salary for <span
          class="user-detail">{{user?.first_name}}</span></label>
        <input id="salary" class="form-control form-control-alternative col-6" type="text">
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="form-control-label" for="salary" name="salary">Specify the salary for <span
          class="user-detail">{{user?.first_name}}</span></label>
        <input id="salary" class="form-control form-control-alternative col-8" type="text">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

See Bootstrap's [column sizing docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/forms/#column-sizing).